# Why I can not edit my postgis layer?

Tags: qgis, postgis

After a working break of a couple of weeks, I start do work on my last project. But I can not edit my postgis-layers anymore! Its possible that I did several system-upgrades, and maybe there was also a postgis-update, and I updated to QGIS 2.12 but I can not exactly tell, what could be the reason.

I have the right ownership of the table and all Privileges (a*r*w*d*D*x*t*)[image: as you can see in the editing-bar - I can not make any changes to the layer]

As you can see in the editing-bar - I can not make any changes to the layer

Answer (score 13):

See this post/answers [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/157541/postgresql-trouble-editing-points-lines-polygons-in-qgis)

I believe that your problem is that you do not have a primary key assigned to your data layer.