Automatically join attributes by location in QGIS
In QGIS, I want to automatically perform spatial joins every time I load a CSV layer with coordinates.
For example, my CSV file contains columns like 'state' and 'mean windspeed' (which are initially empty). When I load the CSV into my project, I want the 'state' and 'mean windspeed' values to be automatically populated from existing shapefiles — one for states and one for mean windspeed. For instance, if I load a coordinate at (37.7749, -122.4194), the 'state' should be filled with 'California' and the 'mean windspeed' with '15 mph'.
How can I automate this process using my tools in QGIS?

By adding a corresponding expression as default value source.

i can't do this because i can't edit csv files, i would have to export them first as a shapefile but then its not autoamted, because new coordinates could not be added automatically. but still thank you for the input.

If you are loading the CSV as layer into QGIS  you could use this approach:
You can set an expression using overlay_intersects() as a default value in the attributes form. E.g. overlay_intersects('layer_windspeed', mean_windspeed)[0]. You also need to check "Apply default on update".
You need to do this for one of your CSV-Layers (the master layer so to say). When you load the next CSV-Layer you can copy and paste its features into the master layer and the desired information should be computed automatically for the respective fields.

Hello, thank you for your answer. But the issue I am facing is that I cannot directly edit CSV files in QGIS, and I have to export them as shapefiles. This creates a problem because it means the CSV file cannot be updated from 'outside' (for example, via Excel), as I need the updates to be reflected automatically in QGIS.

I think you can not achieve your goal without editing the CSV layers. So, I would look into the issue of why you can not edit those layers (e.g. here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/266424/why-is-my-attribute-table-edit-button-greyed-out)

What about using a virtual layer? Will a virtual layer linked to my CSV file update automatically when the CSV is updated?
