# GeoServer complains because osm2pgsql didn’t create primary keys

Tags: qgis, geoserver, wfs, osm2pgsql

I imported OSM data into a PostGIS database using `osm2pgsql`, then served it in WFS via GeoServer.

However, QGIS gets stalled when trying to view these layers.  I found corresponding GeoServer errors in the logs :

```
2020-06-16 14:17:44,394 INFO [geoserver.servlets] - OutputStream was successfully aborted.
2020-06-16 14:17:44,394 ERROR [geoserver.ows] - 
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException
    at org.geotools.xsd.Encoder.encode(Encoder.java:729)
    at org.geotools.xsd.Encoder.encode(Encoder.java:549)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.xml.GML32OutputFormat.encode(GML32OutputFormat.java:151)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.xml.GML3OutputFormat.write(GML3OutputFormat.java:312)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.WFSGetFeatureOutputFormat.write(WFSGetFeatureOutputFormat.java:195)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.response(Dispatcher.java:1030)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:269)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:26)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:69)
    at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:70)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:66)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:41)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:37)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:51)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:52)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:101)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:77)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:46)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException
    at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureCollection.features(ContentFeatureCollection.java:165)
    at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureCollection.features(ContentFeatureCollection.java:52)
    at org.geotools.data.crs.ReprojectFeatureResults.openIterator(ReprojectFeatureResults.java:92)
    at org.geotools.feature.collection.AbstractFeatureCollection.features(AbstractFeatureCollection.java:65)
    at org.geotools.feature.collection.AbstractFeatureCollection.features(AbstractFeatureCollection.java:50)
    at org.geoserver.security.decorators.SecuredFeatureCollection.features(SecuredFeatureCollection.java:43)
    at org.geoserver.security.decorators.SecuredSimpleFeatureCollection.features(SecuredSimpleFeatureCollection.java:74)
    at org.geotools.feature.collection.DecoratingSimpleFeatureCollection.features(DecoratingSimpleFeatureCollection.java:88)
    at org.geotools.gml2.simple.FeatureCollectionEncoderDelegate.encode(FeatureCollectionEncoderDelegate.java:110)
    at org.geotools.xsd.Encoder.encode(Encoder.java:727)
    ... 100 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureSource.getReaderInternal(JDBCFeatureSource.java:624)
    at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureSource.getReader(ContentFeatureSource.java:612)
    at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureCollection.features(ContentFeatureCollection.java:163)
    ... 109 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot do natural order without a primary key, please add it or specify a manual sort over existing attributes
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.sort(JDBCDataStore.java:3483)
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.selectSQL(JDBCDataStore.java:3320)
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureSource.getReaderInternal(JDBCFeatureSource.java:591)
    ... 111 more
```

Searching in particular for `IOException: Cannot do natural order without a primary key, please add it or specify a manual sort over existing attributes`, I identified the issue as [the lack of a primary key](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Anybody-to-confirm-this-WFS-problem-tp5381615p5382597.html), needed for pagination with WFS 2.0.0 (a fix is to disable pagination by unchecking the relative box in the WFS connection settings in QGIS).

I am surprised `osm2pgsql` doesn’t take care of this, am I missing an option ?  What is the best way to fix this ?

### Update

I manually [added primary keys](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/171631/159691), but GeoServer fails to see them, even after reloading the GeoServer webapp, restarting TomCat, using the "refresh" link in the GeoServer PostGIS layers, or removing and re-adding the layers.

I guess I am still missing something ?

Comment: add a primary key to the table

Comment: @IanTurton Yes, I later found [this helpful answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/171631/159691), the tables are currently being updated and I will test asap.  I also found [this related github issue](https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/issues/446).

Comment: Did you actually add a primary key or just a unique id column?

Comment: I used `ALTER TABLE planet_osm_line ADD gid serial PRIMARY KEY;` as suggested in the linked answer.  `\d planet_osm_line` states `gid | integer | | not null | nextval('planet_osm_line_gid_seq'::regclass)
Indexes: "planet_osm_line_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (gid)`.  Anyway to my understanding even a standard new column should appear in GeoServer ?

Comment: might need a vacuum analyse?

Comment: @IanTurton Solution found, it was indeed GeoServer configuration.  Thanks for the mention of the vacuum analysis, I learned something more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *"Cannot do natural order without a primary key, please add it or specify a manual sort over existing attributes"* exception may arise for a layer made of an SQL view.

In this case, it can be fixed by going to the *"edit the SQL view"* page and checking one (or several ?) of the rows of the table as "Identifier".  Note that the selected field won’t be public anymore.

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer : this answer is likely wrong, as hinted by Ian.  Indeed, using the same data with a fresh GeoServer installation, I don’t get the error anymore, although "*Expose primary keys*" is not checked.*

By default, primary keys are not exposed by GeoServer.  This is why they don’t appear in the list of properties of the layer.

They will appear [after you check](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/database/postgis.html) "*Expose primary keys*" in the PostGIS store configuration.

As for `osm2pgsql` not creating primary keys by default, [it doesn’t seem to be on the roadmap](https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/issues/1216) for most backends, but [it is straightforward](https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/pull/1220/commits/4a93a85833999658749b49b570612a3621c28d18) with the new flex backend : just add

```
{ column = 'id', type = 'serial', create_only = true },
```

to your flex configuration.

Comment: GeoServer should use the primary key without needing to expose it